# Expandable ListView's height exceed the window height

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I have a user control `ListView1.xaml` which looks something like this:

```
<Grid>
 <ListView ItemSource="{Binding}">
  ...
 </ListView>
</Grid>
```

In my window I use this control 3 times. Something like this:

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Expander Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <local:ListView1 DataContext="{Binding Source1}"/>
 </Expander>
 <Expander Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <local:ListView1 DataContext="{Binding Source2}"/>
 </Expander>
 <Expander Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <local:ListView1 DataContext="{Binding Source3}"/>
 </Expander>
</Grid>
```

When I set `Height="*"` for each `Grid.Row`, it would divide the space into 3 equally. It is taking empty space even when the first 2 tabs are not expanded:
[image]

If I set `Height="auto"`, it would have what I am looking for: when a tab is collapsed, only the expanded one is taking place:
[image]

But one problem with `Height="auto"` is that there is no scrollbar on the `ListView` because the height of the `ListView` is expanding beyond the height of the window.
How would I be able to keep the expanders behave that way and have scrollbar for each `ListView` when the content is larger that the window?

Comment: I would try maxheight on your listviews. Bind using relativesource to the actual height of the contentpresenter they are in.

Comment: @Andy I tried added ```MaxHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"``` to the ListView but then it won't show any content anymore even when the expander is expanded.

Comment: That's not the contentpresenter, you're binding to actualheight of the listview itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider a tabcontrol for this sort of UI.

Part of the problem is the grid isn't sizing to it's parent when all it's rows are auto.

If you change from using a grid to a dockpanel then you will get scrollbars.

When you expand the second expander then you'll have to decide what you want to happen though. You'd have to close the first or recalculate what size you want each to be in code.

But I think this is a lot closer to usable.

My minimal reproduction uses listboxes.

```
<DockPanel>
    <Expander DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding IntList}"/>
    </Expander>
    <Expander DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding IntList}"/>
    </Expander>
    <Expander DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding IntList}"/>
    </Expander>
</DockPanel>
```

And my viewmodel:

```
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public List<int> IntList { get; set; } = new();
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            IntList.Add(i);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks so much for your reply. I tried your suggestion and used DockPanel. It does bring back the scroll bar for each ListView. It has one tiny problem that when I open the first expander, it would take all the space which make the other 2 expanders "invisible" since they are out of the window.

Comment: And if you have two open then what size are they supposed to be @Jtastic

Comment: I have this behavior set: When one expander is open, the other 2 will close. So only one expander can be open at a time. I want it that when one expander is open, the expander below it won't be pushed out of the UI. For example, if Expander 2 is open, the UI should look like this from top to button: Expander1 (close), Expander2 (open) followed with the content of Expander2, Expander3 (close)